# Mysql Error updating record syntax to use near 't suit to the product which is described above')' at line 1

Tags: php, mysql

here i am trying to insert values from textarea to mysql database from php.

```
<textarea cols="43" rows="5" class="reject-textarea" name="reject_reason"></textarea>
```

Here  `$reject_for = $_GET['reject_reason'];` is the value i am getting from the textarea of html form.

when i type `This product does'nt suit for our requirement` i am getting the error,

error:Error updating record: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'nt suit for requirement')' at line 1

but when i type `This product does not suit for our requirement` i am not getting any error.

i think there is something wrong with "`'`" in `This product does'nt suit for our requirement`

How can i solve this:

```
<?php 
    require_once('configuration.php');
    $product_id = $_GET['product_id'];
    $reject_for = $_GET['reject_reason'];           
            if (isset($product_id,$reject_for)){  
                rejectProduct($product_id,$reject_for);
            } else {  
                echo "Are you trying to do something nasty??";
            }

            function rejectProduct($product_id,$reject_for)
            {
                $conn = new mysqli(db_host, db_user, db_password, db_name);
                if ($conn->connect_error) {
                    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
                } 
                $sql = "INSERT INTO rejected_products(product_id,reason_to_reject) VALUES ($product_id,'$reject_for')";
                $result = $conn->query($sql);
                if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
                    updateProduct($product_id);     
                } else {
                    echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
                }
                $conn->close(); 
            }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is example of sql injection. while you are submitting data to the database you need to sanitize it submitting. there are lot of way to do it 
like

```
$reject_for = MySQL_real_escape_string($_GET['reject_reason']);
```

one good reason to sanitize it is to have more security. if you directly add user input it may be dangerous.

Answer (score 3):

use `mysqli_real_escape_string` like

```
$reject_for = mysqli_real_escape_string($_GET['reject_reason']);
```

Or better you should use [`prepared statements`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `mysqli_real_escape_string` before insert into database

> Escapes special characters in a string for use in an SQL statement,
>   taking into account the current charset of the connection

```
$reject_for = $conn->real_escape_string($reject_for);

$sql = "INSERT INTO rejected_products(product_id,reason_to_reject) VALUES ($product_id,'$reject_for')";
```